# SimpleScreenRecorder records only one side of communication

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, screencast

I am trying to record zoom sessions with [SimpleScreenRecorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/). Unfortunately, if I set Source = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" I get only my counterpart recorded. And if I set Source = Built-in Audio Analog Stereo", I get only my side recorder.

[image]

Can I record both sides somehow?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're just recording a single stream -- what's going to your speakers or headphones, or what's recording you. You need to choose a "source" that has access to both sources of audio. For example, a webcam mic -- if you are using speakers, it can "hear" what you're saying as well as what's coming out of the speakers (i.e. what the other party is saying).

The application has to cancel out what you're saying so that it doesn't play that back to you, which would cause a feedback loop, but that should happen downstream of the screen recorder.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying https://obsproject.com/. You can combine inputs/outputs how you want.